# How to fetch ActivityType metric for each activity in ADF V2 pipeline using powershell?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am not able to find any powershell command to extract ActivityType metric in ADF V2.

Comment: Does the below answer helps your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `az rest` to call [Data factory Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/operations/list) REST API:

```
az rest --method get --url GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/operations?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Comment: Hi @singhh-msft. thanks for your inputs. I am unable to test this due to some corporate proxy issue and will let you know once it get resolved

Comment: Sure, pls keep the community posted. Thanks!